# how can I check if the popup can not show all so then make it more to left?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a scheduler where are some events. If I hover on some event then it shows a popup. The Problem is if I am at the end of the scheduler (scrollend) and want to show the popup then I see only the half of the popup. How can I say when it not can be show the whole popup then make it more left.

if I hover on an event I got some props like the distance from window to the event so then I can add the x and y to show the popup on the event.

```
        eventMouseEnter={(e) => {
     
          setH({x: e.jsEvent.x + 30, y: (e.jsEvent.y - e.jsEvent.offsetY) + (window.scrollY) - (dd.company ? 223 : 218), show: true});
          }
        }
```

But I dont know how can I solve this issue what I have describe above. Look at the image

[image]